# Re-defining SKNode means I have to re-add the node as a child?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

I have a case in my code where it seems like I have to re-add a child node if I redefine what it's pointing to but I don't quite understand why.

For example:

```
_worldNode = [SKNode node];
_childNode = [SKNode node]; //set childNode to point to a node here. 
_childChildNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test"];

[self addChild:_worldNode]; 
[_worldNode addChild:_childNode]; //add childNode to the worldNode
[_childNode addChild:_childChildNode];

//Later on...

[_childNode removeAllChildren]; //1. do I need to do this to clean up _childChildNode first?
_childNode = [SKNode node]; //set childNode to another node.
_anotherChildChildNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test"];
[_childNode addChild:_anotherChildChildNode];

//2. do I need to re-add _childNode to _worldNode now?
```

Doing 1 seems to free up a lot of nodes in my game, but I didn't think that was necessary as I'm pointing _childNode to another node right below, so I thought the node I was originally pointing to (and _childChildNode) would have a refcount of 0 and would be deallocated?

I also don't think I need to do 2, as I've already added _childNode to _worldNode before but my game just seems to go blank if I don't add this line (probably from the removeAllChildren call).

Do you know if I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doing 1 seems to free up a lot of nodes in my game, but I didn't think that was necessary as I'm pointing _childNode to another node right below, so I thought the node I was originally pointing to (and _childChildNode) would have a refcount of 0 and would be deallocated?

You need to remove `_childNode` from its parent:

```
[_childNode removeFromParent];
```

Until you do that, `_childNode` stays in memory, because parent node holds a reference to `_childNode`. Moreover, if you call `removeFromParent`, calling `removeAllChildren` is redundant.

After assigning a new node to `_childNode`, you have to add it to `_worldNode` again, because it is a completely new node:

```
_childNode = [SKNode node];
_anotherChildChildNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test"];
[_childNode addChild:_anotherChildChildNode];
[_worldNode addChild:_childNode];
```

Comment: Ahh makes sense - didn't realise the parent held a reference onto the child node. Thanks!